# Fade out last 5 px of text in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, cagradientlayer

I want to fade out the last 5 px of a UILabel. The label can never be longer than one line. 
At the moment I have the following function.

```
  func addFadeOut() {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [self.theme.darkJungleGreenColor().cgColor, self.theme.darkJungleGreenColor().withAlphaComponent(0.1).cgColor]

        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.95, y: 1)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 1, y: 1)
        self.layer.mask = gradient
    }
```

Can anybody help me how to interpret the start and endpoint?

Comment: Add a semitransparent image 5 px wide. It's the simplest option.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the start points and end points from the width and height of the label.

```
 extension UILabel {

    func fadeOut() {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [self.textColor.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]

        //Get Height and width
        let width = self.bounds.size.width
        let height = self.bounds.size.height

        //Calculate the start points and end points
        let startPointX: CGFloat = (width-5)/width
        let startPointY: CGFloat = (height/2)/height
        let endPointX: CGFloat = 1
        let endPointY: CGFloat = (height/2)/height

        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: startPointX, y: startPointY)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: endPointX, y: endPointY)
        self.layer.mask = gradient
    }
}
```

Comment: Your start and endpoint are not between a range of 0 - 1? correct ?

Comment: No the calculation always gives the result between 0 to 1 range.

Comment: Strange, I'm using Swift 3, there I need to use for example:         let endPointY = (height/2).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: height)

Comment: Yes in Swift 3 modulo is replaced by this 'truncatingRemainder'.

Comment: Than I get wrong values? Please test it in playground

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139751/discussion-between-steaphann-and-ashish-shah).

Comment: I have tested and updated the answer. Now working accordingly.

Comment: This is not working, it's not even compile. Please edit your answer

Comment: Updated the answer.